# Cannot connect to Cloud SQL Proxy

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to use Cloud SQL Proxy for my Kubernetes project.

I follow the guide of [Elixir and Phoenix](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/elixir-phoenix-on-kubernetes-google-container-engine). Under **Connect to your Cloud SQL instance**, that guide says that running `cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/tmp/cloudsql` and `psql -h /tmp/cloudsql/[CONNECTION-NAME] -U postgres` will open the proxy.

So I tried to make a new directory with these commands below.

```
mkdir -p /tmp/cloudsql
chmod +x /tmp/cloudsql
```

and then I tried to connect to Cloud SQL Proxy.

```
cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/tmp/cloudsql/                16:47
2020/10/30 16:47:50 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {&{xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
2020/10/30 16:47:51 Using gcloud's active project: [instance-id]
2020/10/30 16:47:54 Listening on /tmp/cloudsql/instance-id:region:instance-name for instance-id:region:instance-name
2020/10/30 16:47:54 Ready for new connections
```

To connect the proxy, I opened another terminal and entered this `psql` command but failed.

```
psql -U postgres -h /tmp/cloudsql/instance-id:region:instance-name
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Not a directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/cloudsql/instance-id:region:instance-name/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What should I do additionally for connecting to the proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from what I see you are passing a wrong connection name

wrong --> `instance-id:region:instance-name`

correct --> `PROJECT_ID:region:instance-name`

You can find the connection name from the

**console --> Cloud SQL --> INSTANCE --> Connect to this instance --> Connection name**